# How to rigourously define $G^{|A|}$? where G is a group and A being an infinite set.

Tags: group-theory

It is clear to me that $G^n:=G\times G\times ...\times G$. Every member of $G^n$ looks like $(g_1,g_2,...g_n)$.

But how to rigorously define $G^{|A|}$, i.e how to explicitly write elements of $G^{|A|}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$G^A$ is the set of functions $x:A\to G$, endowed with componentwise product and inverses. So to say, you gain access to the $a$-th component of the element $x$ by evaluating it, as a function, at $a$: id est $x_a:=x(a)$. More generally, you can define $\prod\limits_{i\in I}G_i$ as the set of functions $x:I\to\bigcup\limits_{i\in I}G_i$ such that $x(i)\in G_i$ for all $i\in I$. This works fine as a categorical product of groups.

When $G$ is a group, there is another (not the only other) useful notion, sometimes denoted as $G^{(A)}$, which is $$G^{(A)}:=\left\{x\in G^A\,:\, \operatorname{card}\{a\in A\,:\, x_a\ne e\}\text{ is finite}\right\}$$

Comment: +1. To the OP, product and sum notations are also used for infinite powers (and in my experience are more common than exponent notation). This answer presents the product notation; re: sum notation, what this answer calls "$G^{(A)}$" is also denoted "$\bigoplus_AG$" or "$\bigoplus_{i\in A}G$."

Comment: Here to guarantee $\prod\limits_{i\in I}G_i$ to be nonempty, we need Axiom of Choice. Am I correct?

Comment: @Saikat For a family of groups we don't, because we have the function assigning to each $i$ the element $x\in G_i$ such that, for all $y\in G_i$, $xy=yx=y$.

Comment: @Gae. S. : Can you explain how $xy=yx=y$? And are you talking about the function $x:I \rightarrow \cup G_i$ which assigns to each $i$ the element $x(i)$ in $G_i$?

Comment: Are you talking about the identity element $e_i$ present in each $G_i$? and we define $x_0:I \rightarrow \cup G_i$ such that $x_0(i)=e_i$ for all $i \in I.$
Is this why we do not need Axiom of Choice to tell $\prod G_i$ is nonempty?

Comment: @Saikat I'm talking about the map $x\in\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ assigning to each $i$ the identity of $G_i$. You don't need choice for this. If you want to have bonus fun seeing the construction $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$ **always** work, try it in the case $I=\emptyset$.

Comment: @Gae. S. : Well then considering a family $\{A_i\}$ of singleton sets, with $i \in \mathbb{R}$. Can I tell the set $\prod A_i$ is non-empty without the help of Axiom of Choice?

Comment: @Gae.S. : Let $A_i=\{a_i\}$. Then I define $x: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \cup A_i$ such that x(i):=a_i. Hence x is a member of $\prod\limits_{i \in \mathbb{R}} A_i$. I think this is the same logic you used to tell that $\prod\limits_{i \in I} G_i$ is nonempty. Am I correct?

Comment: Ah... So you say that $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is the indexed family of sets (let's call it the function $A_\bullet:I\to\text{Somewhere}$) and *that each* $A_i$ is a singleton. Then yes, it works: you can define $x(i)$ to be the only object such that $x(i)\in A_i$. Or, in set-theoretic jargon, $$x=\{(a,b)\,:\, a\in I\land b\in A_a\}=\{(a,b)\,:\, a\in I\land \exists c, ((a,c)\in A_\bullet\land b\in c)\}$$

Comment: Likewise, $$x=\{(i,e)\,:\, i\in I\land (e\in G_i\land \forall y\in G_i,(ey=ye=y))\}=\\=\{(i,e)\,:\, i\in I\land(\exists g, ((i,g)\in G_\bullet\land e\in g\land\forall y\in g,(ey=ye=y)))\}$$ is an element of $\prod_{i\in I}G_i$.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen this before but I guess a reasonable way to define $G^\mathbb{R}$ would be to say that $f\in G^\mathbb{R}$ is a map

$$f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow G $$

And if I have $f,g\in G^\mathbb{R}$ then $(fg)[x]=f(x)g(x)$, this is a generalization of the $G^n$ case since you can think about elements of  $G^n$ in a similar way as maps from $\{1,...,n\}\rightarrow G$.